# Listview with one sticky header for second row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My layout is a bit complex.

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` in which I host a `ListView`. Whenever the user drags the Listview's top, the `SwipeRefreshLayout` performs a refresh. I also listen for the last visible item of the `ListView` to load next page of records (Endless scroll)

In the list's `adaptor` I have 2 views that I am using. The first one will only be visible in first row, the other view will remain the same for all other rows.

What I want to achieve:

- On top of the row with position = 1 I want to have a sticky header. This means that when I scroll Up, the header will scroll to the top of the screen and will remain in there.
- This sticky header will only be at one row
- if possible I'd like to use a simple implementation as my layouts and adapters are already complex enough.

Waiting for your suggestions.
[image]

Comment: You can set first row of list view as list header. Is that applicable for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt quite get your question the first time, heres the answer attempt round 2.

In your layout add an empty viewgroup (whichever you prefer, though linearlayout seems to work just great), add a scrollListener to your listView and check the position of your sticky view. If its top anchor is below (meaning its visible in the listview) the top of the screen you set the viewgroup visibility to gone, if the top anchor is either touching the top of the screen or below it, you add that view or one just like it to the viewgroup and set its visibility to visible.

You can adjust the position 2 view visibility accordingly to allow for this change to appear seamless. Can help you a bit more once you have some code and are on your way with this change.

Comment: This will not work. As I mentioned, I need to have the sticky header remaining on top of the screen when I scroll up

Comment: Edited my question, this is how i'd do it on a first attempt. Should work, what you're asking isnt that hard, but its not possible to make a listview item magically not move, you have to add some tricks to it.